# Equation typing Double Script error

Tags: math-mode, equations

For the following equation, I am getting the,

```
line 166-Double subscript. ...{i}}\Pi_{n_{1}} v_{n1}(I_{est(1)})u_{n1}_
```

the second line in the following equation is line 166, anyone please help me in finding the error,

```
\sum_{TI}P(I_{Pred}|TI,\delta)P(TI|\delta )=
\sum_{n_{1}...n_{i}}\Pi_{n_{1}} v_{n1}(I_{est(1)})u_{n1}_{n2}\ast v_{n2(I_{est(2)})}u_{n3}_{n4}\ast....\ast u_{n(L-1)} u_{nL}(I_{est(L)})
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please give a minimal working example!

Comment: `u_{n1}_{n2}`  subscript of subscript -> error. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).   While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. But, in this case, I think you just need to add an additional a brace group: Either `u_{{n1}_{n2}]` or more likely `{u_{n1}}_{n2}`.  You seem to have solved it in `\Pi_{n_{1}}` -- so apply similar principle to the other double subscript.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your math code. The problems that throw errors are related to double-subscript issues, which I don't know should be resolved correctly. I've applied some guesses in the code shown below, but that's all they are -- guesses.

You should also replace `\Pi` with `\prod`, `*` with `\times`, `...` with `\dots` (to create properly spaced typographic "ellipses"), and `|` with `\mid`. Some letter combinations, such as "est" and "pred", should be typeset using upright characters. The indexes of summation and multiplication don't look right. And, at some point you employ the variable `v` while at others you employ `u`. Is this deliberate?

The following code should be taken purely as a starting point; it has the virtue of compiling without error, but that's just about all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\est}{est}
\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{{\mathit{TI}}}P(I_{\mathrm{Pred}}\mid {\mathit{TI}},
    \delta)P({\mathit{TI}}\mid \delta )
= \sum_{n_{1},\dots,n_{i}} \prod_{n_{1}} 
v_{n1}(I_{\est(1)})u_{n1n2}\times 
v_{n2(I_{\est(2)})}u_{n3n4}\times\dots\times 
u_{n(L-1)} u_{nL}(I_{\est(L)}) % should that be 'v_{nL}(I_{\est(L)})'?
\]

\end{document}
```